# Excel formula to return an adjacent value when two cells match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, matching

Here is what I'm looking for.  I need to have Excel return a specific value from an adjacent key when 2 cells match.  I attached 2 images here to explain what I'm looking to do.  The first image is where I'm currently at and the second image is where I want to get to.

So for example I need Excel to match cell A1 to J1 and drop the value in K1 into cell E1 (red cell).  I then of course need to run this down all of column E, asking excel to match the number in column A with a number in column J then dropping the appropriate dollar value into column E.

[image: EXAMPLE 1]

[image: EXAMPLE 2]

I've tried the VLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH formulas and none of them seem to give me the answer.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP($A1,$J$1:$K$10,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Please do not add begging statements into titles or posts - it is a vandalism that a volunteer will need to repair. Nothing is urgent here, and it is considered rude to make that stipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track - this is exactly what `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH` are for!

Here's the solution in this case:

```
=INDEX($K$1:$K$10, MATCH($A1, $J$1:$J$10, 0))
```

I'd generally prefer `INDEX/MATCH` to `VLOOKUP` especially if you plan to add columns to your spreadsheet. If you however prefer the `VLOOKUP` solution, it's as @Warcupine commented:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,$J$1:$K$10,2,FALSE)
```

If you're rocking a newer version of Excel (2019+), `XLOOKUP` provides the best of both worlds in my opinion (stable and concise):

```
=XLOOKUP($A1,$J$1:$J$10,$K$1:$K$10)
```

Comment: MAN!  You all are Rockstar's!  Thank you so much!!!!!!!!

Comment: Haha - no problem dude!  Do you mind marking this as the solution?